# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'append'. Did you mean: '_append'?

Tags: yahoo-finance, yfinance

I am trying to download the PE Ratio for 'AAPL' and got the above error.
The following is my code:

import yahoo_fin.stock_info as si

ticker = 'AAPL'

table = si.get_quote_table(ticker)

print(table)

Are there any other ways to get stock fundamentals for a large number of companies (e.g. all companies in SP500)?
Thanks a lot!

line 7, in

```
table = si.get_quote_table(ticker)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

line 295, in get_quote_table

```
data = tables[0].append(tables[1])
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

line 5989, in **getattr**

```
return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'append'. Did you mean: '_append'?